# Book series about a child living among goblins that had a queen and ate goop

Tags: story-identification

I read a book series when I was a child and the only thing I can remember from it is that a little boy was sneaking around a place where goblins lived, and that the goblins had a hive queen and they ate goop. Could anybody identify that series? Sorry, the info is so sparse.

Comment: The information is sparse indeed. Firstly, you could add the years when you were a child; secondly, you could add where you read this (which country), and in what language it seemed to have been published originally.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I think there is enough. Edge Chronicles probably.

Comment: poke @Adamant you might want to post it as an answer now that it's been reopened.